# eclipse java code comment text in first line

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

how do I change the style of java class, method comments in eclipse?

Insted of

```
/**
 * Represents a student enrolled in the school.
 * A student can be enrolled in many courses.
 */
public class Student {

  /**
   * The first and last name of this student.
   */
  private String name;

  /**
   * Creates a new Student with the given name.
   * The name should include both first and
   * last name.
   */
  public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

I would like to have

```
/**Represents a student enrolled in the school.
 * A student can be enrolled in many courses.*/
public class Student {

  /**The first and last name of this student.*/
  private String name;

  /**Creates a new Student with the given name.
   * The name should include both first and
   * last name.*/
  public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

How do I get the text to start in the first line?

Comment: Oh no, please don't.

Comment: I'm not sure but you might get it by following this : window -> preferences -> Java>Code Style>Formatter -> edit -> Comments>Javadocs -> uncheck "/* and */ on separate lines" -> specify profile name and save, then switch to that profile in the preferences window.

Comment: Somehow it does not apply to the code.

Comment: I've edited my comment, I suggested to change the configuration in Comments>Block comments at first but it's actually the conf in Comments>Javadoc which is relevant to your case, make sure your used my updated comment. If you did, make sure your formatter actually ran, depending on your conf it could be any time the file is changed, or only when it's manually called